# Implement security feature using RateLimiter but tooManyAttempts method not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

What i try to achieve is, when a user failed 3 attempts while login that user should having delay on the next login request.

```
trait LoginDelay {
    public function delayOnFailedLoginAttempt( $request ) {
        $key = $this->throttleKey( $request );
        $maxAttempts = config( 'app.max_failed_login_attempt' );
        $delayInSeconds = config( 'app.delay_after_failed_login_attempt' );

        if ( RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts( $key, $maxAttempts ) ) {
            sleep( $delayInSeconds );
        }
    }
    protected function throttleKey( $request ) {
        return $request->ip();
    }
}
```

Here i am using a trait where i separate the logic for the delay on failed login attempt, I used rate limiter tooManyAttempts method where i define a max attempts for a key which is the ip of the current user.
Now i used that traits in my Authcontroller and call that trait function inside my login method when login attempt is going to be failed.

Here is the main issue when i test that login route using postman that function is not work as per the requirement.

Please help me to identify where am i getting wrong.

Note: I am using laravel 10. I'm not installed any auth starter kit (UI, breeze, justStream).

Comment: What do you mean by this "that function is not work as per the requirement"? What's the actual behavior? and how it differs from what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That method return Boolean value based on the max attempt on a specific key, here for example i give max attempt 5 and for key i am using Ip, now  when i crossed max attempt the method should return me true but it still return me false which i don't understand why. am i able to explain you what i actually indicate. @Solrac

Comment: @Lord_Shiva_Mahadev you don't seem to be incrementing the attempts anywhere? have you checked the docs https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/rate-limiting

Comment: @krisgjika thanks for the doc and thanks for pointing out the mistake i made. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Lord_Shiva_Mahadev if you solved your issue, might be good to post your solution for future reference